# Consume Webservice using https protocol

Tags: java, web-services, https

I want to consume a web service over https from a java client.
What steps will i need to take in order to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really, there shouldn't much different from consuming a web service over HTTP. The big thing is that the process calling the web service will have to trust the server's SSL certificate. If the certificate was purchased from a well-known certificate-issuing authority, this usually isn't a problem. Otherwise, the client will want to either trust the root certificate, or the certificate associated with the server's fully qualified host name.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to use the [keytool](https://web.archive.org/web/20100606064854/http://java.sun.com:80/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/keytool.html) command to trust the server's SSL certificate.  I've generally found that it is necessary to run something like this:

```
keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -alias ServerName -file server_cert_file.crt -keystore client_keystore_file
```

Comment: Hi Ian

Thansk for your answer. Do you find that your trsusstore password and server cert password must match up when you do this?

Comment: Strictly speaking, I don't think that they have to match.  I've never done it any other way, though.

Answer (score 0):

Blair says it right. all the same, try it out using SoapUI , which is a web service test client. This is an open source utility : so you get a chance to see how things work under the covers.